# VB.NET Print on each line of a rich textbox separately

Tags: vb.net, printing, textbox, richtextbox

How can I print a line of a richtext and then the second one and so on?

Something like that :

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox2.Line(0), font, Brushes.Black, 30.23622, 139.165354)
```

EDIT:

Now the problem is that if I do not press enter but the text fills the line and move on to the next one, it doesn't count as a line. Any idea?

Comment: I solved that now the problem is that if I do not press enter but the text fills the line and move on to the next one, it doesn't count as a line. Any idea?

Comment: Use a `For` loop, possibly? Or just draw all the text at once, letting the `DrawString` function handle line wrapping.

Comment: Why not use the print function?

Comment: I want every text in a specific location

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a For Each loop like this:

```
For Each line In RichTextBox1.Lines
    e.Graphics.DrawString(line, font, Brushes.Black, x, y)
    y += e.Graphics.MeasureString(line, font).Height
Next
```

remembering to increment y for each line by the height of the string